# Rails 3: Two singular nested resources, one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I'm working on my first bigger project in Rails. It will be a RESTful API.
The situation I've stumbled upon can be described as the following:
I have the models 'Person' and 'Application'.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managed_applications, :class_name => "Application", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
  has_many :owned_applications, :class_name => "Application", :foreign_key => "owner_id"

  # other associations
  has_many :adresses
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Person"
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "Person"
end
```

How should I design my controllers and routes, so that I have the following quite self-explanatory resources working?

```
/applications/<id>/owner
/applications/<id>/manager
/people/<id>
```

The problem is, that when is nest singular owner and manager resources under a "plural" applications resource, all routes end up in the identical 'PeopleController' actions, with the same params.

A bonus would be, if the first two resources would act as the last one in terms of read-only operations (e.g., you could retrieve the addresses of the manager of a specific application just with one request, 'GET /applications/<id>/owner/adresses'). Is that even recommended API design?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is indeed a valid REST approach but I would remove the deep nesting of addresses one level up. Then people will be a shallow resource of its own and thus have its own addresses. I do this because REST nesting of level more than 1 is dicouraged. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html Now let's address the other problem. How will the controller know that the user requested 'owner' or 'manager'. One way is to use default params right in routes like this :

```
resources :applications do
  resource :owner, :controller => 'people', :defaults => {:type => 'owner'}
  resource :manager, :controller => 'people', :defaults => {:type => 'manager'}
end

resources :people do
  resources :address
end
```

Then in your PeopleController:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @type = params[:type] # can be manager, owner or nil
  end
end
```

But beware that here the user can override these default params in the url so I'm leaving the security implications to you.

The other way is to check request.fullpath which yields the full url address. In it you can search for either manager or owner.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, in the end I actually solved it by considering the associations themselves as resources. I'm new here, is it common to edit my question to include my own solution? T.

Comment: I'm new here too :-). But I think it's better to do that than keep it secret.

Comment: @user1241530 you could add a separate answer if you have a valid answer to your question. Don't include the answer in the question, as the answer may not be the best one. This way your question and your answer would have different votes.